# jQuery - One checkbox to un-check all, but remembers original state when toggled

Tags: jquery

The code in the snippet disables all checked states when the `#checkall` is checked, but I want to revert back to the original `checked` state of each checkbox when `#checkall` is unchecked again.

The desired UX is to simulate turning off notifications.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#checkall').click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('#checkboxes').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkall" />
<label for="checkall">Disable</label>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" />

</div>
```

Comment: Why not actually use [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled) with extra styling as necessary. Then the user can still see what was checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do it.

It's generally better to use ".on('change',..." rather than binding directly to the "click" event.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkall').on("change", function () {
        if (!$(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('#checkboxes input[type=checkbox]').each(function (index, elem) {
                var input = $(elem);
                input.prop('checked', input.data('was-checked'));
            });
        }
        else {
            $('#checkboxes input[type=checkbox]').each(function (index, elem) {
                var input = $(elem);
                input.data('was-checked',input.prop('checked'));
                input.prop('checked', false);
            });
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkall" />
<label for="checkall">Disable</label>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add data attribute for those checked checkbox then use the data attribute to select the original checked checkbox

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#checkall').click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('#checkboxes').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    
    $('#checkboxes').find('input:checkbox[data-checked="checked"]').prop('checked', !checked);
    
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkall" />
<label for="checkall">Disable</label>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" data-checked="checked" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" data-checked="checked"  checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" data-checked="checked"  checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" data-checked="checked"  checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The original checked state is stored in .attr('checked'):

```
$('#checkboxes').find('input:checkbox').each(function(x) { 
    $(this).prop('checked', $(this).attr('checked') == 'checked' ? true : false) 
})
```